# Como usar o harlan-generator no Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman

Estou pensando em criar uma webapp usando o [harlan](https://github.com/bipbop/harlan) e acabei descobrindo que ele tem um yo-generator chamado generator-harlan. Pelo que eu entendi ele é como o [generator-angular pro Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html) mas não consigo instalar o generator-harlan pelo npm e não sei que comandos usar pra gerar meu webapp. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Instalação do generator-harlan funcionou com seguinte comando npm: $> npm install -g generator-harlan

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza o README.md do projeto [generator-harlan](https://github.com/bipbop/generator-harlan) carece dessas informações, contudo é muito simples. Basta você possuir o Yeoman instalado, se certifique que tem também a [última versão estável do NPM e NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) no seu computador.

```
$ mkdir new-project;
$ cd new-project
$ sudo npm install -g yo
$ npm install generator-harlan
$ yo harlan # Gera seu projeto.

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |   Welcome to the Harlan  |
   `---------´   |        generator!        |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Your package name: (new)
```